# NHibernate ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP conflicts with DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, pagination

Could anybody please explain why NHibernate on `MsSql2012Dialect` generates query that can not be processed by server? It builds query this way when there is no sorting specified explicitly.

```
...
ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: It is using the `OFFSET` clause, when `PAGING` is needed. In this case, it will select the first 10 rows order by time stamp. You have some kind of paging, right?

Comment: And I found where the problem was. We have SELECT DISTINCT in our query and no ordering. So default ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP that HNibernate generates conflicts with DISTINCT . The error was - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: At the end of the day, if you're using paging but not supplying actual sort criteria, the function that's using this may as well be called "select 10 random rows", since the query as shown gives no guarantees on which rows it will return.

Answer (score 5):

This is unresolved bug registered in [jira](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3594), based on the suggestions, this is my work around:

```
public class MyMsSql2012Dialect : MsSql2012Dialect
{
    public override SqlString GetLimitString(SqlString querySqlString, SqlString offset, SqlString limit)
    {
        var result = base.GetLimitString(querySqlString, offset, limit);

        return result.Replace("ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "ORDER BY 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: The better solution is to provide the ORDER BY column to NHibernate explicitly and include that column in SELECT list.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the question, following query is generated if no ORDER BY is explicitly specified:

```
 SELECT
    distinct this_.ColumnName as y0_ 
 FROM
    [DB].[dbo].Table this_ 
 ORDER BY
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Error is:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Error only occur if BOTH `Projections.Distinct` and `Take(1)` is provided and SQL Server version is above 2012 (`Dialect` is `MsSql2012Dialect` or above).

The better solution is to provide the ORDER BY column to NHibernate explicitly and include that column in `SELECT` list.

```
Session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Select(
            Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property<Entity>(x => x.ColumnName))
           )
    .Where(....)
    .OrderBy(Projections.Property<Entity>(x => x.ColumnName)).Asc()
    .Take(1);
```